# Unable to find the mod_pagespeed in phpinfo page

Tags: php, apache, mod-pagespeed

I have installed apache 2.4 and php5.6 and I enabled mod_pagespeed1.9stable version. i am unable to find the mod_pagespeed in phpinfo page.
but i can able to find in phpinfo page when iam using apache 2.2 and php5.3. can anyone please help me out.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I was  downloaded the mod_pagespeed using below URL

wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_x86_64.rpm                                                                                   
Now install it:

yum install at
rpm -U mod-pagespeed-*.rpm
Restart Apache:

service httpd restart

Comment: did you install Apache also using yum or apt-get?

Comment: you need to install mod_pagespeed_ap24 for Apache 2.4 !

Answer (score 0):

The mod_pagespeed packages install two versions of the mod_pagespeed code itself, `mod_pagespeed.so` for Apache 2.2 and `mod_pagespeed_ap24.so` for Apache 2.4.

explained here
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download